# Can't understand the requirement from the exercise

Tags: c++, algorithm

this https://projecteuler.net/problem=641 is the problem I am trying to solve and below is my half solution.

```
void dice(int n) 
{
    int i, j, dices[n];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dices[i] = 1;
    }

    for(i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j+=i)
        {
             dices[j]= dices[j] > 5?1:dices[j]+1;
        }
    };


    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << i+1 <<  "th dice is :" << dices[i] << endl;
    }
};
```

this is the part I do not get: Let f(n) be the number of dice that are showing a 1 **when the process finishes**. You are given f(100)=2 and f(10^8)=69. Find f(10^36).

from "f(100)=2" I understand that the 100th die should be 2 but f(10^8)=69 loses me.

Comment: Given 100 dice, by the time the algorithm finishes, only 2 will be showing a 1. It's poorly worded, but I'm fairly confident that is the intent.

Comment: `10^8` means 10⁸ = 100000000.  In C++ it means something else, but the requirements aren't being given in C++ syntax.  Some programming languages have used `^` as the exponentiation operator; but that has probably been overshadowed by the fact that TeX and LaTeX use it for typesetting exponents. Anyone who publishes papers in math and related fields knows it.

Comment: @Kaz OP wrote `10^n`, not the question that is linked. You're explaining stuff they already know.

Comment: Can you tell from the problem's description, how many times the _first_ die will be turned? Does that agree with your program? (Please note the description is based on numbering from `1`, while your code uses C++ indexing rule based on numbering from `0`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the problem description again. There is a definition of **f()** there:

> Let **f(n)** be the *number of dice* that are showing a 1 when the process finishes.

It is *not* a value of any specific die. Instead, the value of **f(n)** tells you how many dice in the *n*–dice row show 1 after completion of all turns.